# Python await is not finished but skipped

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I am trying to implement an async database connection library to my FastAPI program, but it seems like python skips my `await` keyword.
My expected behaviour is that the login func will call `get_user_info`, which will print "before calling query" and then call `_query` and print "about to execute" and then print the result.

The actual outcome:

```
before calling query
user: None
INFO:     127.0.0.1:60548 - "POST /api/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
2021-05-24 12:31:44.007 | INFO     | authentication.routes:login:31 - 127.0.0.1 tried to log in with user x
```

my code:

route.py

```
@auth_app.post("/auth/login", response_model=Token, tags=["Authentication"])
async def login(request: Request, form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    credentials_exceptions = HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect credentials.",
            headers={"Authenticate": "Bearer"}
        )
    username = form_data.username
    password = form_data.password
    async with MysqlConnector() as conn:
        user = await conn.get_user_info(username)
    print("user:", user)
    logger.info(f"{request.client.host} tried to log in with user {username}")
    if not user:
        raise credentials_exceptions
```

My MysqlConnector() class:

class MysqlConnector:

```
async def __aenter__(self):
    await self._create_connection()
    return self

async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    await self.connection.disconnect()

def __await__(self):
    return self.__aenter__().__await__()

@staticmethod
def _create_conn_string():
    return f"mysql://{MYSQL_SETTINGS['user']}:{MYSQL_SETTINGS['password']}@{MYSQL_SETTINGS['host']}:" \
           f"{MYSQL_SETTINGS['port']}/{MYSQL_SETTINGS['database']}"

async def disconnect(self):
    await self.connection.disconnect()

async def _create_connection(self):
    MYSQL_SETTINGS['use_unicode'] = True
    MYSQL_SETTINGS['charset'] = 'utf8'
    self.connection = Database(self._create_conn_string())
    await self.connection.connect()

async def _query(self, sql_query, dictionary=False, **kwargs):
    print("about to execute")
    await self.connection.execute(query=sql_query, values=kwargs)
    self.res = await self.connection.fetch_all(query=sql_query)
    print("result: ", self.res)

async def get_user_info(self, username: str) -> str:

    sql_query = """
    CALL `sp_get_user`(:username);
    """
    try:
        print("before calling query")
        await self._query(sql_query, username=username)
        result = self.res
        print("result:")
        print(result)
    except IndexError:
        return
    user = User(  # User is a pydantic model
        user_id=result[0],
        username=result[1],
        first_name=result[2],
        last_name=result[3],
        role=result[4],
        hashed_password=result[5],
        email_addr=result[6],
        phone=result[7],
        desc=result[8],
        last_login=datetime.strptime(result[9], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        active=result[10],
        api_access=result[11]
    )
    print("user:", user)
    return user
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you please include the entire `get_user_info`  method?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm trying to be helpful...but have you tried to check if `conn` gets established correctly into the `async with` loop?